# Sending data from Marketing cloud Data Extension to External Database on real time

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

My requirement is to update external database real time or equivalent to real time from my Data Extension. My Data extension get updated on a basis on real time so now I want the same to be happened to my external database. Anyone have done this already ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need to use Marketing Cloud [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm) to [Retrieve Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm) from your Data Extension. 
There is the sample .net, Java, PHP and SOAP envelope written as examples.

Although if your Marketing Cloud Data Extension is being updated by something in real-time, then why would you not want that process to update your External Database in the same automation.